# What's "chosen" about Jews?

Tags: words, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, parashas-yisro

Jews are commonly referred to as "the chosen people". I've heard it comes from [Exodus 19:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0219.htm#5) ("וִהְיִיתֶם לִי סְגֻלָּה מִכָּל הָעַמִּים", "ye shall be Mine own treasure from among all peoples", JPS). But what does this mean exactly? What is this "chosenness" or status as a "treasure"? Specifically does it mean

- that we're singled out for rights? for better treatment, by God, in this world? in the next?
- that we're singled out for responsibilities?
- that we're singled out for (*kivyachol*) emotions? that God loves us more?
- more than one of these? Something else?

**To be clear:** I'm asking specifically about Exodus 19:5. I'm asking about "chosen" only as an interpretation of Exodus 19:5, and not independently. (The reason for this is that it would be very hard to answer "what does 'chosen' mean when people say it" from sources; interpretation of a verse in Exodus may be easier.) If, or to the extent, "chosen" is not an interpretation of Exodus 19:5, I don't seek to know what "chosen" means.

---

I see [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jews_as_the_chosen_people) on this, but it doesn't address this much and is unclear where it does. I seek sourced answers *only*, please.

Comment: You sure it isn't devarim 14? http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0514.htm

Answer (score 3):

The answer is quite complicated and requires a lot of background information/perspective first. This lecture from Ohr Somayach provides the best framework I've come across.

[Mankind and the Role of the Jews - by Rabbi Uziel Milevsky](http://dafyomireview.com/audio/m04-3_flaws_of_man_and_role_of_jews.mp3) (former chief Rabbi of Mexico)

Some Main Points

- Mishna in Pirkei Avot - all evil comes from 3 roots - jealousy, lust, honor
- Sin of Adam consisted of 3 flaws
- Mankind was then tested at each of the 3 flaws to rectify them (Kain/Abel - jealousy, flood - lust, Tower of Babel - honor)
- Mankind failed at all 3 tests. New system must then be established in the world to rectify humanity. No longer all of humanity but a subgroup.
- 3 Patriarchs - Abraham, Isaac, Jacob partially rectify 3 flaws and establish new system
- Their descendants must now rectify 3 flaws in themselves and afterwards in the messianic era, bring all of humanity back to pre-sin state

There is much more to it. See the mp3.